# Can we use xamarin.android code in xamarin.ios?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I have an app developed in xamarin.android. Now I want to develop same app in xamarin.ios. So can I use any code (classes, methods written by me) that is written for xamarin.android app in xamarin.ios app.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  Code that is not platform dependent (domain, models, services, data, etc) can be placed into a PCL or shared project and used by both apps.  Code that is platform dependent (UI, other device interaction) will need to be written for each platform.

Comment: Yes with PCL and we can do this. But the app is already developed in xamarin.android (Native). Now I want to create xamarin.ios (native) app for same. So I want to know if I can use any code of xamarin.android in xamarin.ios.

Comment: You will need to refactor your Android code to put the code you want to share in a shared library.

Comment: You can't just reference xamarin.android from Xamarin.iOS but you should be able to litterally just drag some files [Classes, Repository etc.] into a PCL and reference the PCL from both. TBH these really should have been in a PCL all along. IMHO the only code that should be in a platform specific project is platform specific code the rest should be in a PCL. If  for no other reason to enforce SOC and encapsulation.